# Getting Errors on newly created GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

After creating new GKE cluster ERROR appear in log console with those messages:

```
{"level":"warn","ts":1604669511.0549798,"caller":"internal/metricsbuilder.go:100","msg":"http client error","timestamp":1604669511051,"value":0,"labels":"map[container:sidecar gke_component_name:addons/kubedns instance:10.4.2.57:10054 job:addons namespace:kube-system pod:kube-dns-7c976ddbdb-52vg6]"}
{"level":"info","ts":1604669530.922167,"caller":"scrape/scrape.go:972","msg":"","level":"warn","scrape_pool":"addons","target":"http://10.4.2.2:8093/metrics","msg":"append failed","err":"non-nil metric or metric descriptor"}
```

Those are warn and info  level messages. But console says that is an ERROR level message. How to fix that?
[Console View with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ywza.png)

Comment: Seems like an issue with GKE itself. The best thing you could do would be to open a [new case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases) (if you have a support plan) or refer your issue to the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) specifying the exact way to reproduce it. I don't believe that this will be the correct forum to address this specific issue.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue also. Did you open a ticket or figure out what was happening?

Comment: Have the same issue, have you resolved it?